# Doctrine2 - Custom persister

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm busy working on a project and I've ran into a slight issue. I was just wondering whether there is any way to customize the persist action of a specific entity? In my case specifically I want to, on update, remove some fields from other tables before re-saving the entity.

Let's, for arguments sake, say my entity that I want a custom persist action on looks like this:

```
/**
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class A {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="B", mappedBy="bar")
    * @ORM\Column(name="foo")
    */
    private $foo;

    //Some additional getters and setters here
}

/**
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class B {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="A", inversedBy="foo")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bar", referencedColumn="id")
    */
    private $bar;

    //Getters and setters here. 
}
```

Now I know with a simple example like this doctrine will automatically just update $bar in class B if you update that, but let's just say I'd like to first remove $bar completely (not just update it) and re-save it with the new value? Is this possible?

This could also just be done manually before persisting in my update action, but that feels a bit hacky?

The actual code I want to do this with is much too long to post here, so I'm just opting for a simple proof-of-concept here.

Thanks for any assist!

**EDIT**

Technically the other entities will be related to the current one, via a OneToMany/ManyToMany/ManyToOne relationship, as in the example above. So isn't there something like preHydrate that I can use to clear *current* data before hydrating the entity with the submitted data?

Comment: Due to separation of concerns this kind of logic should not be contained in the entity itself - it's harder to reuse your entity class if you have such logic inside the entity, got me? the listener/subscriber is a better way to solve this generally.

Comment: OK I see what you mean... Thanks for the help!

Comment: I would recommend using a `prePersist` and/or `preUpdate` subscriber and clearing out the related stuff in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **event-listeners** or **-subscribers** instead of `LifecycleCallbacks` (i.e. `@PrePersist` ) as recommended in Cyrus's answer.

Using LifecycleCallbacks you don't have access to unrelated entities while you can change/remove these with a listener/subscriber where you have direct access to the entity-manager with dependency injection.

Please see the documentation chapter [How to Register Event Listeners and Subscribers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html).

Comment: So you're suggesting I add perhaps a POST_SUBMIT event listener to my form? I think I'm just confused as to how I should clear all the data that has been persisted without losing the data that has just been submitted? Seeing as the data is hydrated back to the entity on submit? Or have I got a hold of the wrong side of the stick here?

Comment: I don't mean a form-event listener/subscriber - Doctrine has it's own events that you can listen or subscribe to. A listener-service is being tagged with `doctrine.event_listener` and an event like `prePersist` while a subscriber-service is tagged with `doctrine.event_subscriber` can supply it's subscribed events in the `getSubscribedEvents()` method as you can see **[here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html#creating-the-subscriber-class)**. these events get triggered i.e. if a new entity gets persisted or the entitymanager is flushed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use prepersist:

```
/**
* @ORM\PrePersist
*/
```

There are preupdate, preremove, etc.

Here you have all the info to do that: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

Comment: This answer doesn't suit the question's condition:  `i want to remove some fields from other tables before re-saving the entity` ... as you can't remove or change unrelated entities using `LifecycleCallbacks`. Please see my answer.

Comment: He is right, I forgot this, you can only modify this entity, no others.

Comment: Cyrus and @nifr could you please check the edit I made and make any suggestions based on that?